# Не загружается страница в webbrowser c#

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser

Добрый день! Почему не прогружается страница "nekto.me/chat" в webbrowser? Вылетают следующие ошибки и происходит анимация загрузки.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

---

[image: 7]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70740/discussion-on-question-by-tuttifrutti-----webbrowser-c).

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки со скриптами в webBrowser обычное дело и от сайта это практически не зависит.
Используйте `webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;`

Comment: ошибки-то пропадут, но чат не загрузится в любом случае. Мне кажется ошибки указывают на причину вечной загрузки

Comment: А так вы еще хотели чтобы чат работал?! С webBrowser про это надо забыть :) Или сменить инструмент. Не ну правда, этот `webBrowser` убог чуть менее чем полностью.

Comment: Я пытался уже и с cefsharp загрузить - всё равно вечная загрузка :с Какие есть ещё варианты?

Comment: Есть у это чата API ? Может стоит написать полноценного клиента работающего через API, не?

Comment: Может и есть, но я так и не нашел

Comment: вот статейка про chatwss.js
https://pikabu.ru/story/arkhitektura_brauzernogo_klienta_4856364

Answer (score 0):

Контрол WebBrowser - это режим эмуляции IE7 (по крайней мере, если ты с реестром ничего не делал). Так что всё равно не заработает. Но если очень интересно:

1. Никакими вебсокетами там даже и не пахнет.
2. 246я строка с полследнего скриншота закачивается запятой, которую, кажется, надо удалить.